# How to remove radial distortions from images using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, distortion, radial

I think I should be using `cv::remap` to remove the distortion but can't figure out what the the maps `const Mat& map1, const Mat& map2` to should be to achieve this.

Should I be using the `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap` to find out the values? If so, I'd really appreciate an example. I do not have the intrinsic camera parameters or don't know how to calculate them. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking to remove the distortion caused by the camera lens you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906523/176769) I wrote some time ago, which has intructions and references on how to do proper camera calibration.

I also suggest [this post](http://aishack.in/tutorials/calibrating-undistorting-opencv-oh-yeah/), which has good info on the procedure as well and uses the C++ interface of OpenCV.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to remove distortion from the lens. Going over the links now :)

Comment: The second link is dead, unfortunetly. Could you provide a new one?

Comment: [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140223092539/http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah).

Comment: @karlphillip magnificent

Comment: Turns out that the page is not gone, just moved. [New location](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/) but unfortunately still have to use wayback machine to download the full-size checkerboard.

Comment: Hi, I post my question here as a comment because I think it might not get a lot of attention. Camera calibration is something very specific.
I read the answers you provided but unfortunately was unable to use this info in my situation. Would it be possible for you to share your insights?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225943/how-to-correctly-calibrate-my-camera-with-a-wide-angle-lens-using-opencv

Comment: @privetDruzia It's been 6 years since I last played with this. Sorry, my memory is quite terrible. Good luck!