# Opencv: correcting radially distorted images when chessboard images are not available

Tags: opencv

How do I recover correct image from a radially distorted image using OpenCV?  for example:

[image]

Please provide me useful links.

**Edit** 
The biggest problem is I neither have the camera used for taking the pic nor the chessboard image.
Is that even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355180/how-to-remove-radial-distortions-from-images-using-opencv

Comment: @amdn The biggest problem is I neither have the camera used for taking the pic nor the chessboard image.

Comment: You only have to compute the parameters once for each camera. In your sample image you would measure whether the mosaic elements lie on a line after undistortion. In general you want to achieve that straight lines in world space are visible as straight lines in image space, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not much to do if you don't have the camera, or at least the model of it. As you may know a usual camera model is pin-hole, this basically consist in the 3D world coordinates are transformed (mapped) to the camera image plane 2D coordinates.

[Camera Resectioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning)

If you don't have access to the camera or at least two chessboard images, you can't estimate the focal, principal point, and distortion coefficients. At least not  in a traditional way, if you have more images than the one that you showed or a video from that camera you could try auto or self calibration.

[Camera auto-calibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_auto-calibration)

[Another auto-calibration](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/FUSIELLO3/node4.html)

[yet another](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/plain/vdl/vdl_upload/103_8_faugeras92camera.pdf)

[Opencv auto-calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/autocalib.html)