# Get camera intrinsics data from the web

Tags: web, computer-vision, aframe, camera-calibration

I have a web based AR app using A-Frame. Is there a way I can get camera intrinsics data (focal length, principal point, pose, frame etc.) from the web?

This question was asked over 7 years ago here, so I was wondering if there were any updates:
[Generic web camera calibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859115/generic-web-camera-calibration)

I've explored getUserMedia(), but that will only provide video streams (tracks) and the properties related to such (facing mode, frameRate, height, width). This is not what I need.

DeviceOrientationEvent (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/device-orientation) uses the accelerometer, compass and gyroscope in phones but not the camera.

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible. There are no Web APIs that give you that info.